# Возможный редирект браузера при заходе на https протокол

Tags: android, ios, http, безопасность, https

Написал маленькое приложение для телефонов. Суть приложения - у юзера в приложении есть браузер, в котором скрыта строка адреса сайта (юзер вообще её не видит) и юзером возможен вход только на один сайт (https//www.mysite.ru/), данные которого передаются только по https протоколу. Вот вопрос - если пользователь подключился к какому-нибудь wi-fi роутеру, этот роутер отслеживает сайт https//www.mysite.ru/ - и как только кто то пытается зайти на сайт https//www.mysite.ru/ , то роутер переадресует его на левый адрес, где юзер так же вводит свой логин и пароль (и их соответственно похищают). вопрос - возможно ли так перенаправить юзера с https протокола?

Comment: вы уверены, что этот вопрос относится к ios и android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В HTTPS сначала устанавливается шифрование, с рукопожатием и проверкой сертификата и только после этого, если сервер предоставил верный сертификат и соединение успешно установлено, отправляется запрос. Сделать редирект без подмены сертификата, своим, который нормальный браузер не пропустит, невозможно. Но если запрос отправляет ваше собственное приложение, а не стандартный браузер, то вы должны проверить предоставленный сертификат на валидность и подпись доверенного центра сертификации.

Comment: спасибо за развернутый ответ, но запрос посылает встроенный браузер android по вот этому рецепту http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/mybrowser.php возможна подмена?

Comment: В принципе это движок многих браузеров. Наверное проверка дложна быть встроенной. Но браузеры при кривом сертификате обычно спрашивают у пользователя разрешение на на продолжение сессии. Не надо ли это как то самому проверять и каково его дефолтное поведение, если таких проверок нет - я не знаю. Предлагаю найти сайт с кривым сертификатом (ну или если веб-сервак твой собственный, то самому сделать самоподписной сертификат) и попробовать зайти на него через приложение. Зайти при кривом сертификате конечно не должен.

Comment: вы оказались правы, попробовали на wi fi поставить редирект, приложение ошибки не выдало, но  на указанный в редиректе сайт не зашло, просто выдало белый экран.